# PHP: how to search a list of objects by field?

Tags: php, object

I'm quite new to PHP.
I'm trying to implement an API backend for a simple contacts manager web-app.
I want to avoid the complexity of a database, just use filesystem.
I will need to perform standard CRUD on my data.
The PHP object structure I adopt right now for my data is:

```
"id-A": {
    "name": "Alice",
    "age": 27,
    ...,
},
"id-B": {
    "name": "Bob",
    "age": 32,
    ...,
},
...,
```

The first question is: which is the best way to scan the objects list by "age" field, for example?
The second question is: is this a commonly used data structure, or could you suggest a better one, to map a list of objects (persons, in this example)?

Comment: Really, I'd use a database - but if you're absolutely certain you want to use the filesystem you could go down the XML route (which gives you `getElementById`) with DOMDocument which means you could find the specific user first, or create a class which implements PHP's Iterator which would allow you to specify how you'll traverse the object : http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php - or you can simply traverse StdClass objects with a foreach loop.

Comment: Perhaps PHPLinq is an option? http://phplinq.codeplex.com/

Comment: @signpainter: it is not: if I had to add a software level, I'd use a regular database... :-)

Comment: @CD001: I suppose I will go with your first suggestion... :-)) Thanks!